# Remove multiple lines from csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

This is my code so far, I have many lines in a CSV that I would like to keep, but if it's the 3rd line, then ignore

This is the line I'd like to be omitted if it is not the third row:

```
Curriculum Name,,Organization Employee Number,Employee Department,Employee Name,Employee Email,Employee Status,Date Assigned,Completion Date,Completion Status,Manager Name,Manager Email
```

it is appearing every 10 lines or so, but i want it removed if its not the first row (always the third)

```
import csv, sys, os

#Read the CSV file and skipping the first 130 lines based on mylist
scanReport = open('Audit.csv', 'r')
scanReader = csv.reader(scanReport)

#search row's in csv - print out list 
for file in glob.glob(r'C:\sans\Audit.csv'):

    lineNumber = 0
    str - "Curriculum Name"

    with open('first.csv', 'rb') as inp, open('first_edit.csv', 'wb') as out:
        writer = csv.writer(out)
            for row in csv.writer(inp):
                if row[2] != " 0":
                    writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: You might want to ask a question, as it stands I vote to close this because it isn't clear what that question might be. Be sure to check the site guidelines how to ask good questions though!

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this in that loop:

```
index = 0
for row in csv.writer(inp):
    if (index != 3) or (index == 3 and row[2] != " 0"):
        writer.writerow(row)
    index += 1
```

I am not familiar with the csv module, so I kept all your stuff assuming it is correct (I don't think you need that module for what you are doing though...)

More info on `enumerate` [here](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/enumerate.html).

EDIT:
To check if it's that line:

```
def IsThatLine(row):
    return row[0] == "Curriculum Name" and row[1] == "" and row[2] == "Organization Employee" and ....
```

Then the `if` can become:

```
if (index != 3) or (index == 3 and not IsThatLine(row)):
```

Comment: how do i do, does not equal 3rd line?

Comment: I have edited my `if` line to make it even more explicit: the `index != 3` makes sure that all lines, except the third gets printed. The `(index == 3 and row[2] != " 0")` makes sure that the 3rd line only gets printed if `row[2] != " 0"`, which is the condition you had already

Comment: what does enumerate do?

Comment: (You can remove the `index == 3` safely, I just wanted to make the code more explicit)

Comment: I gave a link to the `enumerate` function in the answer.... http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/enumerate.html

Comment: i appreciate your help, but i need the row deleted if it matches this Curriculum Name,,Organization Employee Number,Employee Department,Employee Name,Employee Email,Employee Status,Date Assigned,Completion Date,Completion Status,Manager Name,Manager Email

Comment: TypeError: '_csv.writer' object is not iterable

Comment: Fixed the answer, no need to use enumerate, just increment the index yourself.

Answer (score -1):

Could you please be more specific in your question?
Would you like to remove any line containing the following description?

*Curriculum Name,,Organization Employee Number,Employee Department,Employee Name,Employee Email,Employee Status,Date Assigned,Completion Date,Completion Status,Manager Name,Manager Email*

Or would you like to remove only the third line (row) of this csv file?

Comment: you have to post a comment for asking for clarifications.

Comment: Ops sorry, just started in replying questions. Good lesson. But I could not add a comment anyway. Not enough reputation points.

Comment: sorry, im trying to remove the line that looks like if it's not the 3rd line in csv file

Comment: @K0nst4nz4 see here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303472/getting-downvotes-because-you-dont-have-enough-rep-to-comment